# Time conversion to hexadecimal (byte array) and reverse

Tags: javascript, arrays, hex

I tried since yesterday to find out the reverse of this formula:
I work with HART (Highway Addressable Remote Transducer) Protocol and the specification said this:

> "... for the DEFAULT_VALUE, the constant-expression must resolve to an
> unsigned 4-byte or 8-byte integer. example 4-byte TIME_VALUE encoding
> for 05:14:26 could be expressed as: DEFAULT_VALUE  =
> ((5*60+14)*60+26)*32000;"

this value is equal with: ‭603712000‬ -> to byte array -> 23 FB EA 00

Can anyone please help me to find the reverse formula? for example 444800000 -> to byte array -> ‭1A 83 1C 00‬.. this number first is divided with 32000 and it's equal to : 13900, and from here I want to obtain the readable time format: hh:mm:ss (like in the above example).

I made this functions but seems to not work as I expected:

```js
secondsPassedToTime = function (seconds) {

    var decimalTime = seconds / 86400;
    var hour = decimalTime * 24;
    var minutes = (hour % 1) * 60 // --> (hour % 1) -> get fractional part from number: 1.9 = 1 + 0.9
    var seconds = (minutes % 1) * 60

    hour = (~~hour).toString().length < 2 ? "0" + (~~hour).toString() : (~~hour).toString(); // --> (~~hour) -> get int from float: 1.9 = 1
    minutes = (~~minutes).toString().length < 2 ? "0" + (~~minutes).toString() : (~~minutes).toString();
    seconds = (~~seconds).toString().length < 2 ? "0" + (~~seconds).toString() : (~~seconds).toString();

    var time = hour.toString() + ":" + minutes.toString() + ":" + seconds.toString();
    return time;
};
console.log(secondsPassedToTime(13900))
```

here I get a possible readable format, but when I transform this to byte array is not 1a 83 1c 00 is totally another value.. 1A 82 9F 00. One of these functions doesn't work properly.

```js
timeToHartTimeByteArray = function (time) {

    var byteArray = new Array();
    var regex = /^[0-9]{2}\:[0-9]{2}\:[0-9]{2}/;
    if (time.match(regex)) {
        time = time;
    }
    else {
        throw "Invalid format for TIME! Format must be: hh:mm:ss";
    }
    var time = time.split(":");
    var hours = parseFloat(time[0]) * 3600;
    var minutes = parseFloat(time[1]) * 60;
    var seconds = parseFloat(time[2]);
    var finalTime = hours + minutes + seconds;

    finalTime = finalTime * 32000;

    var hexTime = finalTime.toString(16)

    if (hexTime.length != 8) {
        var hexTime = "0" + hexTime;
        byteArray.push(hexTime.slice(0, 2))
        byteArray.push(hexTime.slice(2, 4))
        byteArray.push(hexTime.slice(4, 6))
        byteArray.push(hexTime.slice(6, 8))
    }
    else {
        byteArray.push(hexTime.slice(0, 2))
        byteArray.push(hexTime.slice(2, 4))
        byteArray.push(hexTime.slice(4, 6))
        byteArray.push(hexTime.slice(6, 8))
    }
    return byteArray;

};

console.log(timeToHartTimeByteArray("03:51:39"))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the problem, it was the first function, the calculation was completely wrong:

```js
secondsPassedToTime = function (seconds) {
    var hour = seconds * 0.00027778;
    var hh = (~~hour).toString().length < 2 ? "0" + (~~hour).toString() : (~~hour).toString();
    var minutes = (hour - hh) * 60.000;
    var mm = (~~minutes).toString().length < 2 ? "0" + (~~minutes).toString() : (~~minutes).toString();
    var seconds = (minutes - mm) / 0.016667;
    var ss = (~~seconds).toString().length < 2 ? "0" + (~~seconds).toString() : (~~seconds).toString();
    
    return (hh + ":" + mm + ":" + ss)
};
console.log(secondsPassedToTime(13900))
```

And now with this output, the second functions convert to the correct hexadecimal value:

```js
timeToHartTimeByteArray = function (time) {

    var byteArray = new Array();
    var regex = /^[0-9]{2}\:[0-9]{2}\:[0-9]{2}/;
    if (time.match(regex)) {
        time = time;
    }
    else {
        throw "Invalid format for TIME! Format must be: hh:mm:ss";
    }
    var time = time.split(":");
    var hours = parseFloat(time[0]) * 3600;
    var minutes = parseFloat(time[1]) * 60;
    var seconds = parseFloat(time[2]);
    var finalTime = hours + minutes + seconds;

    finalTime = finalTime * 32000;

    var hexTime = finalTime.toString(16)

    if (hexTime.length != 8) {
        var hexTime = "0" + hexTime;
        byteArray.push(hexTime.slice(0, 2))
        byteArray.push(hexTime.slice(2, 4))
        byteArray.push(hexTime.slice(4, 6))
        byteArray.push(hexTime.slice(6, 8))
    }
    else {
        byteArray.push(hexTime.slice(0, 2))
        byteArray.push(hexTime.slice(2, 4))
        byteArray.push(hexTime.slice(4, 6))
        byteArray.push(hexTime.slice(6, 8))
    }
    return byteArray;

};

console.log(timeToHartTimeByteArray("03:51:40"))
```